# Error of MultiLineString object is not iterable

Tags: error, shapely

Simply I just want to convert a MultiLineString data to a list but get the error:
`TypeError: 'MultiLineString' object is not iterable"`

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString

coords = [((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 20.0)), ((20.0, 0.0), (20.0, 20.0))]
mlines = MultiLineString(coords)
mls_list = list(mlines)
```

I use Python 3.7.8 and Shapely 2.0.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `geoms` method for multipart geometries.

```
mls_list = list(mlines.geoms)
print(mls_list)

# OUT:
# [<LINESTRING (0 0, 0 20)>, <LINESTRING (20 0, 20 20)>]
```